# ASP.NET System.IO.File.Delete not working - physical path, but a virtual path was expected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to delete a file from a server via ASP.NET I am trying to use System.IO.File.Delete like so:

```
try
{
    var filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("C:/www/project/Images/" + landingCells.imageBytes);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
```

But every time it returns false, I am able to write a file to the server:

```
try
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:/www/project/Images/" + filePath, bytes);
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
```

But I am unable to delete the file, yes the file path and name are correct are the folder has full control, what am I doing wrong?

This is the error I got:

```
An error occured: ‘C:/www/project/Images/ANW00012018053015551423458244a89b23-5ed7-42a3-a2fc-4b15a90fb3cf.jpg' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.
```

Comment: Are you sure the file path is correct? `"C:/www/project/Images/" + landingCells.imageBytes` seems wrong.

Comment: don't swallow exceptions. what exception are you getting?

Comment: don't specify a full path with `MapPath`

Comment: maybe in use, check you are disposing elements properly, etc. exception message is not trivial !

Comment: Is this a string by the way `landingCells.imageBytes`, from the naming convension seems to be byte array or something ?

Comment: This is an error `An error occured: ‘C:/www/project/Images/ANW00012018053015551423458244a89b23-5ed7-42a3-a2fc-4b15a90fb3cf.jpg' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.`

Comment: What is your reasoning behind using Server.MapPath? Why do you think it's necessary to use that if you're passing a full path into it?

Comment: `Server.MapPath` returns **physical path** from virtual path. `Server.MapPath("~/images/myimg.jpg")` returns physical path to `domain.com/images/myimg.jpg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason we use `Server.MapPath` is we do not want to hard-code the file path inside the code.

```
try
{
    string fileName = "Sample.jpg";
    var filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + fileName); // Do not pass byte array here
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
catch
{
    // Do not swallow the exception. Instead, log them to persistant storage.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all very risk approach is hardcoding the path to folder. What if admin will move an app to disk D?

IMHO the issue is here: 
`var filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("C:/www/project/Images/" + landingCells.imageBytes);`

You're trying to access a stream so the path is very long and looks more or less like "C:\www\project\Images\0x00a00efe............."(so the path here is very long). Instead of `imageBytes` property you should use file name.

Also, when you're getting similar issues, catching exception and logging it, is very usefull.

Comment: I know the name says imageBytes, but its actually a string with the filename: ANW00012018053015551423458244a89b23-5ed7-42a3-a2fc-4b15a90fb3cf.jpg, so I am using a file name

Comment: and what says exception (stack trace)? could you catch it and post here more details?